# Why does Windows 10 has some text as ClearType but not others? How can I enable Clear Type on it?

Tags: windows-10, anti-aliasing, cleartype

I'm using Windows 10, I'd noticed that some fonts is blurrier than others.
With a propper zoom, I'm able to see that some of them has sub-pixel antialias (ClearType) but not for some of them.

[image: Windows Explorer]

Windows Explorer

[image: Email App]

Email App

How can I make this fonts sharp again?

Comment: Already any solution found?